# What is the difference between Search traffic and Organic traffic in Google Analysis Mobile App?

Tags: google-analytics, mobile, google-ads

There is search traffic and organic traffic in segments in Google Analysis android mobile app. what is the difference between these two traffic types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, **search traffic** refers to two different *dimensions* that define all the traffic that is coming from search engines (e.g. Google) while **organic traffic**  refers to only one *dimension* with *medium* = organic.

In other words, **search traffic** refers to the “organic search” and “paid search” dimensions (medium=cpc,ppc,organic,etc)
and **organic traffic** refers to “organic search” dimensions (medium=organic) only.

So if you look at the app acquisition overview report and select the search traffic segment you will notice these two dimensions in all the other reports, try the same by using the organic traffic segment and you will see only one dimension.

Now, for instance if you need to craft a report to measure your SEO campaign performance use the **organic traffic** segment only.

Or if you want to check your AdWords campaign performance use the **paid traffic** segment only